Add spaces to tag names
How do you like the idea of ​​adding a space in the label name?
Only we need to make a verification system so that labels like " " are not allowed. But like this - "functional programming" are allowed.
Also, if you agree with this idea, maybe replace everything - in labels for separating words with spaces?
Regarding the tag separator in the question, I think you can just write the tags in square brackets, as is done in the search bar.

Perfectly spaced: https://i.sstatic.net/TMm1MapJ.png ....

That would seem to make it complicated to add tags to a question as normally you press space to indicate that you've finished writing one tag and are on to the next one.
We'd get lots of questions with functional and programming tags created by mistake and we'd forever be trying to burninate such mistakes.
functional-programming seems perfectly readable.
